# How to set a SubWindow in JavaFX always on top (even if a game is in fullscreen mode)?

Tags: javafx

I created a small application and I need a **sub-window** that is **ALWAYS** on top :D

*anotherstage.setAlwaysOnTop(true)* works fine, but if I start a game in fullscreen-mode my sub-window will hide. How can I prevent that?